# Htaccess url creation and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

people

I've have problem with my code

The problem is that I have my php file that gets the $_GET values like down below:

```
// Look if there is a page asked
if(isset( $_GET['section'] )) {
    // Page asked lets see what we do with it
    if(isset( $_GET['subtopic'])) {
        $path = "content/" . $_GET['section'] . "/" . $_GET['subtopic'] . ".php";
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            // Asked ?section=&subtopic= lets check if exist then include
            include($path);
        }
        else {
            // Asked ?section=&subtopic= not found throw 404
            echo '404 - not found';
        }
    }
    else {
        $path = "content/" . $_GET['section'] . "/index.php";
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            // Asked ?section= existed include
            include($path);
        }
        else {
            // Asked ?section not found throw 404
            echo '404 - not found';
        }   
    }
}
else{
    // No page asked throw default page
    include('content/home/news.php');
}
```

so when I have my ip its like this IP/?section=home&subtopic=news

what it stands for is that section is the folder where it should get like shown in above code. but I use a .htaccess file for making the ?section=home to make it IP/home/?subtopic=news but when I do IP/home/?subtopic=news it gives me /home/ not found I think the problem is in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\W+)/$ /index.php?section=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/$ /index.php?section=$1&subtopic=$2
```

this is my .htaccess file to accomplish it but it just doesnt want to work so I hope you guys can help me.

Kind regards,

Jeffry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , i suggest you to make it a bit easier, passing only one variable would be easier than two variables, and then you can deal with the variable to extract the 2 data you need. To do that you have to put this code on your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?data=$1 [QSA]
```

now on your `index.php` file you have the 2 data on your `$_GET['data']` all you have to do is to explode the string like this

```
$data = explode("/", $_GET['data']);
$section = $data[0];
$subtopic = $data[1];
```

and then you can do all your tests... don't forget to activate the "`rewrite module`" on your apache server

Answer (score 0):

if you using '/' in regular expression - better need add symbol \ before /

This .htaccess directives working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/$ /index.php?section=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/$ /index.php?section=$1&subtopic=$2
```

Also need enable apache .htaccess files.
You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read AllowOverride All in apache config or virtualhost file. This tells Apache that it's okay to allow .htaccess files to over-ride previous directives.
example:

```
    <Directory /var/www/> # /var/www/ - web site root directory
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

You must reload Apache before this change will have an effect.